# How to test parachain + Slot Auction + Crowdloan in Rococo chain?

Tags: parachain, rococo, crowdloan, auctions

My parachain's unit tests can run no problem.

I am aware of "Rococo Slot Request" from https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/rococo/#request-your-parachain-slot

and in this section talking about Testing a Parachain
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk#testing-a-parachain

But that does not mention about testing the Slot Auction and Crowdloan in a live environment, i.e. the Rococo chain.

A) How can I do such a test?

B) Is this all manual tests, meaning all button clicking can only be done by a real person?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to run a local rococo with [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch) where you can quickly launch your own relaychain and parachain. You can also tweak the config file to not automatically onboard your parachain. With the sudo permission you can easily test crowdloan and slot auction.